# Bootstrap 5 col-sm-6 and col-md-4 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In small and medium screens col-sm-6 and col-sm-4 is not working in bootstrap-5 and it is working fine in large screen.
my requirement is in small screen i have to show 2 images and medium screens i have to show 3 images.
in large screen it is showing 4 images but in small and medium screens only not showing properly.
iam new to to the bootstrap.
please help to solve the issue.

For reference please find the attached images
[image: Small Screen].

[image: medium screen]

[image: large screen]

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                     <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person One</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Two</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Four</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Five</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Six</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Six</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Seven</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Eight</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Nine</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Nine</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything seems to be working like it's supposed to. I can't figure what you're trying to do exactly

Comment: @EzequielS.Sandoval In small screens  have to show only images and medium screens three images. but in my case it is showing all 4 four images for small and mediul screens.

Comment: So you want to hide 1 of those images if medium screen size and hide 2 if small screen size, right?

Comment: @EzequielS.Sandoval This is Slider in small screen have to show 2 images initially and Automatically slide to third and fourth images. in medium screen have to show 3 images initially and Automatically slide to third and fourth images.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with bootstrap by itself, in this case you would need to render images inside your slider on a different way, using js or whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

just add those two line of condition on your individual div which one you want to hide or show
`d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-none col-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3`

`d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-block col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3`

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                     <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="row">
                              
                                <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-none col-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person One</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-block col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Two</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="row">
                              
                                <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-none col-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person One</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-block col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Two</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="row">
                              
                                <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-none col-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person One</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-md-block col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Two</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="single-box">
                                        <div class="img-area"><img src="assets/images/img.jfif"></div>
                                            <div class="img-text">
                                                <h2>Person Three</h2>
                                                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 
                     </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about small screens col-sm-6 ?

Comment: Do you want 2 box in mobile screen?

Comment: in small screen i have to show 2 images and medium screens i have to show three images.

Comment: Yes exactly 2 box in mobile scree

Comment: Hey! I have updated my answer, please let me know if your problem is solved.

Comment: i will check and let you know